# Unexpected code path h2 db

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc, h2

Пользуюсь h2 базой данных 1.4.195. 
Пишу запрос:

```
  String selectFriends = "SELECT * FROM " + ACCOUNT_TABLE_NAME + " JOIN(SELECT friendId FROM " +
                FRIENDS_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE accountId = ?) AS tbl ON " + ACCOUNT_TABLE_NAME + ".id = tbl.friendId;";
try (PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(selectFriends)) {
            statement.setLong(1, id);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                resAccount.setFriends(createFriends(resultSet));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


 private List<Account> createFriends(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        List<Account> friends = new ArrayList<>();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            friends.add(createAccountFromResult(resultSet));
        }
        return friends;
    }
```

Временная таблица tbl подчёркивается ещё на этапе компиляции.

Вот stack trace целиком:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: переделал запрос "select * from accounts where id in (select friendId from friends where accountId = ?);"; Работает, но было бы интересно узнать, в чём проблема, нагуглить нечего толком не смог.

Comment: мало исходного кода и стектрейс не весь, сложно изучить причину ошибки

Comment: @Visman спасибо, справил, должно быть database

Comment: @DaysLikeThis дописал исходный код, выложил стак трейс, ошибка в строке PreparedStatement. Думаю просто не получается почему то из такого sql запроса создать statement. Хотя вроде как он вполне себе типичен. )

Comment: попробуйте * заменить на имена нужных колонок, судя по стектрейсу ошибка парсинге стейтемента. Еще нашел запрос на баг https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/X_R-jt5FMvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Парсер не смог обработать wildcard (*) в запросе. Замените его на настоящие имена колонок либо имена с алиасами.